# Ball Bouncing in a circle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uikit

i am successfully bouncing ball in side the **UIView**.

i have create ball class inside in it i am using following code to move the ball.

```
    self.center=CGPointMake(self.center.x + mXSpeed, self.center.y + mYSpeed);
if (!CGRectContainsRect(self.superview.bounds, self.frame))
{

    if (self.frame.origin.x<self.superview.bounds.origin.x)
        mXSpeed=abs(mXSpeed);
    if (self.frame.origin.x>self.superview.bounds.size.width-self.frame.size.width)         
        mXSpeed=-abs(mXSpeed);  
    if (self.frame.origin.y<0)//self.superview.frame.origin.y)          
        mYSpeed=abs(mYSpeed);
    if (self.frame.origin.y>self.superview.bounds.size.height-self.frame.size.height)           
        mYSpeed=-abs(mYSpeed);

    //mYSpeed=-mYSpeed;
}
```

now i want to bounce the ball inside the circle Area, how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Ok lets assume that your frame in 200 by 200 pixels.
So the center of you circle in at 100,100

You can calculate the distance from this point like this:

```
dist = sqrt((x-100)^2+(y-100)^2)
```

When this number is 100 or bigger you need to change your direction.

Once yo have this, you will have to introduce a direction vector and figure out how to deflect of a circular object, but i'll let you have a go at that first.

Comment: hey i try to use your code my view size is 240 * 240 so use like, float   dist = sqrt(((int)self.frame.origin.x-120)^2+((int)self.frame.origin.y-120)^2); but i am getting maximum value is 14 or 15 its never goes above it.

Comment: put some logging on what self.frame.origin.y is giving

Answer (score 0):

Just bound x and y of the center to be always at most `radius` distance (where `radius` is the radius of your ball) from the circumference. It's should be pretty straightforward geometry.